# Web page crashing using update data every 1 second in react-tabulator

Tags: reactjs, tabulator

I am using react-tabulator 0.18.1. I have a table whose data needs to be updated every 1 or 2 seconds so for that i have used updateData function but on using that the DOM nodes are increasing continuously in the web page making it to crash on chrome browser.I have some editable columns also in table so replaceData and setData functions cannot be used as it will remove the edited data. Here is a simple code snippet

```
const Test=()=>{
    const table=useRef(null);

    const updateData=(data)=>{
        table.current.updateData(data).then(function(){
            console.log("update called");
            table.current.redraw(true);
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        })
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        const timeId=setInterval(()=>{
                updateData(data);
        },2000);
      return ()=>clearInterval(timeId);
    },);

    return(
        <div>
            <ReactTabulator
          onRef={(ref) => (table.current = ref.current)}
          columns={columns}
          data={data}
          layout="fitData"
          options={options}
        />
        </div>
    )
}
export default Test;
```

```
const options = {
  height:250,
  groupBy:["id","name"],
};
```

data is coming from backend.

Comment: Can you show as a working demo in form of a codesandbox or anything like that along with sample input?
Because I tried your code as such with my own sample data. It works fine.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-cache-ddokdg?file=/src/App.js. This is the link but its a sample code the one am working on has a lot of columns and am using a complex group by function also. Please try it in chrome and keep the scroll to the end in the table then you will be able to see that the DOM nodes are increasing continuously.

Comment: I can't reproduce it in my end. I see that there are 7 records in yours table with their groups. After every n second, I only see those 7 entries. @Stuti

Comment: The thing is as you can see those entries so the usual behaviour should be like on update the number of nodes will increase but after update it must come back to the previous number of DOM nodes but in my case it keeps on increasing with every second the update is happening .@SM1312

Comment: you should be using replaceData, not updateData

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `replaceData` function for rapid in-place data replacement, not the `updateData` function

```js
table.current.replaceData(data)
```

Comment: I have used it but on using it as am using group the selected group will close every time the replace is happening and also i have some input cells so on replace i am not able to input data in them as replace will happen every 1 second.